# Scalability of websockify?

Tags: websocket, websockify

I new with websockify. So here my situation.
Our company have servers written in C# to handle about 1000 to 2000 raw TCP sockets connect per time from Flash and mobile client to play a game online. So we consider to port Flash to Html5 and use Websockify and port native protocol build on TCP at client but still remain native TCP at server side(for mobile client still work).

So I guess Websock client and Websockify server connect via Websock protocol and Websockify and our server connect via TCP protocol

If I right, so can we do that to handle kind of amount connections on Websockify and it performance

Answer (score 2):

The are implementations of websockify in several different languages. The python implementation is the default and has the most additional functionality (auth, logging, etc). However, the basic function of websockify is just to bridge transports (WebSockets to TCP sockets) so it's actually not that difficult to implement. There is a C version that you might look to get maximum efficiency although it is quite dated and probably buggy.

That being said, the python version of websockify is fairly scalable. Each new connection to websockify starts a new child process so it should be linearly scalable to the amount of CPU/memory on your host (separate processes means no GIL contention). Also, websockify is horizontally scalable if a single host can't handle the load of all connections. In other words, you could just put a load balancer (that supports WebSockets) in front of multiple websockify servers.

Also, websockify (the python version) is easy to configure to support multiple targets per instance of websockify. I've added a [wiki page](https://github.com/kanaka/websockify/wiki/Token-based-target-selection) describing how to do that.